# Install custom *.deb by using Kickstart ( Ubuntu Server 14.04 )

Tags: 14.04, server, package-management, automatic, kickstart

I'm trying to create an Ubuntu Server automated installation by using Kickstart.
I also need to install third-party packages without internet connection.

The installation end successful, but packages are not installed by using `dpkg -i /pool/extras/*` in the `%post`script within the ks configuration file, while **they are properly installed if downloaded from the internet** using `apt-get`.

How do I install them? How can i install the packages under `/pool/extras` ?

Comment: you may need to do them individualy `sudo dpkg -i /path/filename.deb`. if you forgot the sudo try again.

Comment: I'm using `dpkg -i /path/*.deb` that is equal. Anyway in kickstart  `%post` script, `sudo` is no required. The problem is that I'm not sure to point to the correct path.

Comment: `dpkg -i /pool/extras/*.deb` should do it if pool is in the root directory. if it is in kickstarts directory then `dpkg -i pool/extras/*.deb`

Comment: I just thought of something. /pool/extras has to be inside the chroot file system?

Comment: I don't know, but I'm not using the flag `--nochroot`

Comment: if I understand the process correctly. the base files system is copied, then it chroots into it to setup. thus the files need to be within the chroot

Comment: Maybe I found a solution. Look at [Offline Installation](http://lms.onnocenter.or.id/wiki/index.php/Remaster_Ubuntu_Server) paragraph.

**You will need to copy them on the cd and create a repository**

Comment: yes, that should do it. then kickstart can install from the CD's repository